# "To be is to do" — "To do is to be" — "Do-be-do-be-do": what does this mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> To be is to do. —*Socrates*
>   To do is to be. —*Plato*
>   Do-be-do-be-do. —*Sinatra*

I saw it on some shirts or somewhere. I don’t understand what it means when those sentences are put together.

Comment: More [here](http://www.i18nguy.com/humor/doing-being.html)

Comment: @Henry: haha, Nietzsche and God. =))

Comment: Kurt Vonnegut, Deadeye Dick.

Comment: I first saw this when I was a kid. It was in a Peanuts cartoon. The quotes were attributed differently. "To be is to do" is a synopsis of Sartre. "To do is to be" likewise for Nietzsche.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is supposed to be humorous.

The first two lines are contemplations on life and are supposed to be very profound. They were spoken by very famous philosophers from Greek history who talk about life and what it is to be alive.

Frank Sinatra was a famous American swing singer around the mid 1900s. The *Dobedobedobeo* is a vocal sound from music of that era. It is meaningless, a sound used only to help with the harmony of a song or fill in notes when there are no lyrics.

By putting the three together, the last line makes a joke of the first two, either by saying that Frank Sinatra was just as profound as the other two, or that Socrates's and Plato's thoughts were no more deep/important than Sinatra's nonsense line.

Comment: There's an old saying: "Humor is like a frog: you can dissect it if you want to, but the results are interesting only to professionals and the frog tends to suffer in the process."

Comment: I completely agree but for the sake of the question... Also, I actually heard that quote for the first time just the other day, funny you should be saying it now. Any idea where it came from?

Comment: At the first time I saw it, I also guessed it is a joke but I didn't understand. Now I do. Thank you.

Comment: So funny!!! :-)

Comment: It should be pointed out that Plato and Socrates said no such things and the quotes as attributed are fanciful.

Comment: @TheRaven -- the attributions in the joke vary.  Nietzsche is often invoked.  @Karl -- I had always assume it to be Twain (if you're talking to me at all) but the Google-consensus is that it's E.B. White, which makes far more sense, as Twain grew up long before high-school biology became what it is today.

Comment: @TimLymington -- we were (if memory serves) talking about *my* joke ("Humor is like a frog...") and who said it.

Comment: @Malvolio - I've been away for a while. A long while. Thanks for the reference (E. B. White).

Comment: Just heard the Chairman of the Board sing "Strangers in the night" (1966). In the closing bar, he sings "do be do be do."

Comment: According to one user, whose suggested edit was rejected earlier today, the *do-be-do-be-do* can be heard in Sinatra's  rendition of "Strangers in the Night". Which confirms rajah9's comment.